# I can't retrieve the Date greater than or equal to a specific date in Sql.

Tags: mysql, sql

```
String sql="select * from offerpoolride 
WHERE date >= '1997-05-05'";
```

I am a beginner and Can anyone please help me how to retrieve those?

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use backtick for date

SELECT * FROM `offerpoolride` WHERE `date` >= '1997-05-05';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about ANSI-SQL, but in T-SQL you would use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [date] >= '19970505'
```

So the date is input in format 'yyyyMMdd'.  I am assuming your field is called date...

Answer (score 0):

you should be comparing dates as dates

```
String sql="select * from offerpoolride WHERE date(my_date) >= date '1997-05-05'";
```

It should do your job.